# SQL query Pivot Many to Many to Many Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot, transpose

Tables are as follows:

Role

```
    Id     Name
     1      Author
```

Object

```
    Id     Name
     1      Blog
     2      Post
     3      User
```

Permission

```
    Id     Name
     1      Create
     2      Read
     3      Update
     4      Delete
```

RoleObjectPermission

```
    RoleId     ObjectId     PermissionId
      1           1              2
      1           1              3
      1           2              1
      1           2              2
      1           2              3
      1           2              4
```

Desired query result for Role.Id = 1:

```
    Object    Create    Read    Update    Delete
     Blog       0         1        1         0
     Post       1         1        1         1
     User       0         0        0         0
```

I attempted to follow this [site](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/) as well as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234789/sql-query-for-transpose-of-a-dynamic-table), but those examples were only for a dynamic rows pivoted to columns and static columns pivoted to rows.

The query will only be used for one Role at a time. I need the query to handle new Objects and new Permissions

My SQL so far:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';

SELECT 
    @columns += N', pi.'+QUOTENAME([PermissionName])
FROM
    (SELECT [Name] AS [PermissionName]
     FROM [dbo].[Permission] AS p
     GROUP BY [Name]) AS x;

SET @sql = N'

SELECT [ObjectName], ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + ' 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         oP.[Name] AS ObjectName,
         (SELECT COUNT(rop.RoleID) 
          FROM [dbo].[RoleObjectsPermissions] rop, [dbo].[Object] o,
               [dbo].[Role] r, [dbo].[Permission] p 
          WHERE
              rop.RoleID = r.ID AND rop.ObjectID = o.ID 
              AND rop.PermissionID = p.ID 
              AND r.ID = rP.ID AND o.ID = oP.ID AND p.ID = pP.ID) AS [Quantity], 
         oP.[Name] 
     FROM
         [dbo].[RoleObjectsPermissions] ropP,
         [dbo].[Object] oP,
         [dbo].[Role] rP,
         [dbo].[Permission] pP 
     WHERE
         ropP.RoleID = rP.ID AND ropP.ObjectID = oP.ID 
         AND ropP.PermissionID = pP.ID 
         AND rP.ID = 2) AS j 
PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR [Name] in 
               ('+STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', pi.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')+')
    ) AS pi;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**EDIT 1**:

I modified the table entries to provide the scenario where a role won't have any permissions on an object as well as partial permissions on another

**EDIT 2**:

This is the final @sql variable that gave me what i was after. I basically took Xedni's answer instead of inner joining all the relationship tables, i left joined a sub query around all the objects. very cool stuff!

```
    @SQL = 
    concat
    ('
        select 
            [Object],
            ', @Exp, '
        from
        (
            select 
                [Object] = o.Name,
                sub.PermissionName,
                sub.PermissionId,
                sub.RoleName
            from dbo.Object o
            left join (
                select
                    ObjectId = rop.objectId,
                    PermissionName = p.name,
                    PermissionId = p.id,
                    RoleName = r.name
                from
                    dbo.RoleObjectsPermissions rop
                    inner join dbo.Permission p 
                        on rop.PermissionId = p.Id
                    inner join dbo.Role r
                        on rop.RoleId = r.Id
                where r.Id = 1
            ) sub on sub.ObjectId = o.ID
        ) s
        pivot (max(PermissionId) for PermissionName in (', @Fields, ')) p'
    )
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*****************************
Test Harness
*****************************/
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Role') is not null drop table #Role
create table #Role
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(128)
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Object') is not null drop table #Object
create table #Object
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(128)
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Permission') is not null drop table #Permission
create table #Permission
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(128)
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#RoleObjectPermission') is not null drop table #RoleObjectPermission
create table #RoleObjectPermission
(
    RoleId int,
    ObjectId int,
    PermissionId int

)

insert into #Role values (1, 'Admin')
insert into #object values (1, 'Blog')
insert into #Permission
values
    (1, 'Create'),
    (2, 'Read'),
    (3, 'Update'),
    (4, 'Delete')
insert into #RoleObjectPermission
values
    (1, 1, 1),
    --(1, 1, 2),
    (1, 1, 3),
    (1, 1, 4)

/*********************
 Dynamic Pivot
*********************/
declare 
    @Fields nvarchar(max),
    @Exp nvarchar(max),
    @SQL nvarchar(max)

select 
    -- list of columns
    @Fields = 
        stuff
        (
            (
                select concat(',', quotename(name))
                from #Permission
                order by Id
                for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
        ),
    -- List of statements which evaluate to 0 if null
    @Exp = 
        stuff
        (
            (
                select concat(', ', quotename(name), ' = iif(', quotename(name), ' is null, 0, 1)')
                from #Permission
                order by Id
                for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
        ),
    @SQL = 
        concat
        ('
            select 
                [Object],
                ', @Exp, '
            from
            (
                select 
                    [Object] = o.Name,
                    PermissionName = p.name,
                    PermissionId = p.id,
                    RoleName = r.Name
                from #RoleObjectPermission rop
                inner join #Object o
                    on rop.ObjectId = o.Id
                inner join #Permission p 
                    on rop.PermissionId = p.Id
                inner join #Role r
                    on rop.RoleId = r.Id
                where r.Id = 1
            ) s
            pivot (max(PermissionId) for PermissionName in (', @Fields, ')) p'
        )

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```